# Loading a key from memory in Crypto++

Tags: c++, crypto++

I'm trying to save a public DLIES key to memory and then read it again, but I keep getting exception `BER decode error`. I use `ArraySink`, `ArraySource` and a `char[64]` buffer to transfer the key between two `CryptoPP::DLIES<>::PublicKey`. I even verify that the public key is good. What am I missing?

Below is the full sample that doesn't work properly. How to modify it so that it'll properly load the key?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gfpcrypt.h>
#include <filters.h>
#include <osrng.h>

int main() {
    try {
        CryptoPP::DefaultAutoSeededRNG rng;

        CryptoPP::DLIES<>::PrivateKey privateKey;
        privateKey.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 10);

        CryptoPP::DLIES<>::PublicKey publicKey;
        privateKey.MakePublicKey(publicKey);

        if (!publicKey.Validate(rng, 3)) {
            std::cout << "Something wrong with public key." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        byte buf[64];
        CryptoPP::ArraySink sink(buf, 64);
        publicKey.Save(sink);

        CryptoPP::ArraySource source((const char *)buf, sink.TotalPutLength());
        CryptoPP::DLIES<>::PublicKey pk;
        pk.Load(source);
    } catch (CryptoPP::Exception &ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've seen that issue (or variants of it) happen frequently. Also, `ArraySource` and `ArraySink` are kind of new. I think they are only available for 5.6 and above. If you are working with 5.5 or below, you need to use `StringSource` and `StringSink`. And +1 for using `DLIES`. I *think* that's the only time I've seen it used.

Comment: I used DLIES, since I trust discrete logarithm based cryptography more than RSA-like ones (RSA, LUC). Also, according to benchmarks on Crypto++ site it's still much faster than the ones I would really like to use - based on elliptic curves.

Comment: Did this make your radar from the Crypto++ wiki: [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme)? Its written for `ECIES`, but it applies to `DLIES` - just swap out the `ECIES` gear for the `DLIES` gear. And be sure to see the note about Bouncy Castle at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lied in not setting `pumpAll=true` 3rd parameter of the `ArraySource` constructor. After adding it, it worked. Another working solution was to use `ByteQueue` instead. For the sake of completeness, I paste both working examples below.

`ArraySource` version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gfpcrypt.h>
#include <filters.h>
#include <osrng.h>

int main() {
    try {
        CryptoPP::DefaultAutoSeededRNG rng;

        CryptoPP::DLIES<>::PrivateKey privateKey;
        privateKey.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 10);

        CryptoPP::DLIES<>::PublicKey publicKey;
        privateKey.MakePublicKey(publicKey);

        if (!publicKey.Validate(rng, 3)) {
            std::cout << "Something wrong with sent public key." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        byte buf[64];
        CryptoPP::ArraySink sink(buf, 64);
        publicKey.Save(sink);

        CryptoPP::ArraySource source(buf, sink.TotalPutLength(), true);
        CryptoPP::DLIES<>::PublicKey pk;
        pk.Load(source);

        if (!pk.Validate(rng, 3)) {
            std::cout << "Something wrong with received public key." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    } catch (CryptoPP::Exception &ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`ByteQueue` version (which I found more convenient in the end):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gfpcrypt.h>
#include <filters.h>
#include <osrng.h>

int main() {
    try {
        CryptoPP::DefaultAutoSeededRNG rng;

        CryptoPP::DLIES<>::PrivateKey privateKey;
        privateKey.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 10);

        CryptoPP::DLIES<>::PublicKey publicKey;
        privateKey.MakePublicKey(publicKey);

        if (!publicKey.Validate(rng, 3)) {
            std::cout << "Something wrong with sent public key." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        CryptoPP::ByteQueue queue;
        publicKey.Save(queue);
        CryptoPP::lword size = queue.TotalBytesRetrievable();

        byte buf[64];
        queue.Get(buf, size);

        CryptoPP::ByteQueue queue2;
        queue2.Put(buf, size);
        CryptoPP::DLIES<>::PublicKey pk;
        pk.Load(queue2);

        if (!pk.Validate(rng, 3)) {
            std::cout << "Something wrong with received public key." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    } catch (CryptoPP::Exception &ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"The problem lied in not setting pumpAll=true 3rd parameter of the ArraySource..."* - the issue occurs with a `StringSource` too. Its because the `bool` `pumpAll=true` is coerced into the integer argument (and without warning, even with `-Wall -Wextra`). And it happens when the `bool` is coerced into the attached `BufferedTransformation` for other objects (i.e., `NULL`).